# Reference Error inside ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting, ngoninit

I am receiving an error on in my console that says `ERROR ReferenceError: sortedArr is not defined` after I have defined it and sorted it.

Here is my app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, OnInit } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'Contacts';
  contacts: any[] = this.contacts;

  constructor (private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      //Pull JSON data from REST API
    this.httpClient.get('***URL TO JSON DATA***')
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.contacts = data;

        //Sort JSON object
        let arr = this.contacts;
        let sortedArr = arr.sort( (a, b) => {
          return (typeof a.name === 'string') - (typeof b.name === 'string') || a.name - b.name || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
          }););
        console.log(sortedArr);
    });
  }
```

The sorted array of objects is being bound to my HTML on my page in my web app, but it isn't in the console. Why would I be getting a ReferenceError when I have just defined AND sorted this array?

The real reason I am asking is because I need to do some different things to this array of objects to have it behave with my HTML correctly. It has allowed me to sort it via the function I wrote, but I cannot call another method on the `sortedArray` variable because its saying it isn't defined.

Comment: Which line is causing the error? I doubt this is the console.log that you showed. If you use that variable outside of subscribe block it will be undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are importing OnInit from the wrong library

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

change it to:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
```

Typo: `);`--> remove this and it will work `let` keyword limits the variable scope to the block and because of typo `);` you are not able to access it outside the scope of the block.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      //Pull JSON data from REST API
    this.httpClient.get('***URL TO JSON DATA***')
    .subscribe((data) => {
        this.contacts = data;

        //Sort JSON object
        let arr = this.contacts;
        let sortedArr = arr.sort( (a, b) => {
          return (typeof a.name === 'string') - (typeof b.name === 'string') || a.name - b.name || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
          }););--> remove it
        console.log(sortedArr);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Great catch! I moved it to the right import, but that unfortunately still did not resolve the issue. Still getting `ERROR ReferenceError: sortedArr is not defined`

Comment: This did it and it makes sense. I was closing the subscribe method a little too early. Thank you!